# ViewScoped issues in JSF 2.0 and alternative solutions

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

I came across a fairly interesting issue when using ViewScoped beans as described in details on BalusC's blog http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html, under section "@ViewScoped fails in tag handlers".

What are the alternatives for those using those tags? (especially <ui:decorate>, <ui:composition>, <ui:include> which I guess is used extensively in JSF apps like mine).

Is there a way to get a unique id of the view and then store the necessary data for the view in the session scope by using some combination of the unique id and whatever else as the key?

Can anyone point to blogs or other alternative approaches? pro and cons of each approach maybe?

Comment: Are you sure that you understand the concrete issue? Are you really binding attributes of `<ui:decorate>`, `<ui:composition>` and `<ui:include>` to a view scoped bean? What exactly is the concrete functional requirement for this?

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand this and that is the problem, I am not sure but your blog points to the best description of the problem. I am using a @ViewScoped bean and everytime there is a refresh of the page (ie a null/void returned from an action), the values (especially Lists, Maps) in the bean are cleared. I think that is related, is it not?. Let me know if I need to share the code.

Comment: Are you using `<ui:someTag someAttribute="#{someViewScopedBean.someProperty}">`? If not, then the particular issue doesn't apply to you.

Comment: BalusC, thanks for the clarification. I finally got this working. I had incorrectly assumed that param objects were request scoped and so was not available in a view scoped bean. It turns out that is not the case. In fact param objects can be injected into a view scoped bean. So all is well. Your feedback helped a lot to clear this up. If you get to read this, please close this question as I don't need an answer.